# Orientation preserving linear map (determinant form)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, multilinear-algebra, dual-spaces

Greub, Linear Algebra, introduces the concept of *Oriented vector spaces*.
Basically, given a skew symmetric $n$-linear form on a $n$ dimensional space (a determinant form) two determinant forms $\Delta$ and $\Delta'$ are equivalent iff
$$
\Delta=\alpha \Delta' \quad\to\quad \alpha > 0.
$$
A basis is positive (for a given orientation) iff $\Delta(v_1,\cdots,v_n)>0$.

> Q1 Is the dual basis positive iff the basis is positive?

I think yes. The dual determinant form is defined by
$$
\Delta^*(v^1,\cdots, v^n)\Delta(v_1,\cdots, v_n)= \det\big((v^iv_j)\big)
$$
which for dual basis becomes (Am I correct?)
$$
\Delta^*(v^1,\cdots, v^n)\Delta(v_1,\cdots, v_n)= 1,
$$
thus one is positive iff the other also is.

> Q2 In the following screen shot I do not understand the sentence *and not on the choice of the representing determinant functions[=determinant form]*

[image: Book]

If I change $\Delta_E$ to $\Delta'_E:=-\Delta_E$, then $\lambda$ has to change sign to preserve the equality?
Probably the sentence is correct, but I miss something conceptual.

Comment: Regarding your Q2: as you said, two determinant forms are equivalent if $\Delta' = \alpha \Delta$ for some positive $\alpha$. The phrase "and not on the choice of representing determinant" means if you trade $\Delta_E$ or $\Delta_F$ for different (but equivalent) determinants, then the $\pm$ sign of $\lambda$ will not be affected.

Comment: @Nick Thank you, I missed it. It does not depend on the representative choice, but it does depend on the chosen orientation.